# If $A^3 = 2I$, prove that matrix $A - 2^{\frac{1}{3}}I$ is not invertible

Tags: matrices, inverse, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

If $A$ is a square real matrix and $A^3 = 2I$, how can I prove that matrix $A - 2^{\frac{1}{3}}I$ is **not** invertible?

I know it can be solved using the characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$, but I was looking for a way to solve it by some clever techniques, like matrix multiplication.  I am trying to avoid using determinants and eigenvalues if possible.

Comment: The identity matrix satisfies $I^3 = I$ but $(1-2^{1/3})I$ is invertible. Are you sure you have question right?

Comment: Can $A$ be complex or is it real?

Comment: Hmmm.. The Argument boils down to whether this real matrix admits a real eigenvalue...

Comment: $B:= 2^\frac{-1}{3}A$.  Then $B^3=I$ and $B-I$ is invertible with $B:=\begin{bmatrix}0 &-1 \\1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ which is a contradiction.  My guess is you meant for the field to be $\mathbb Q$ not $\mathbb R$ even thought you've stated reals.

Comment: I think the correct statement is in odd dimension!

Comment: I think your mistake was to assume that if 2 is an eigenvalue of $A^3$, then $2^{1/3}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, which is not true: it could be a complex root of $\lambda^3=2$. This can happen if you have a rotation matrix, like @AndreaMarino pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$ (A^2+ 2^{1/3} A + 2^{2/3} I) ( A- 2^{1/3} I) = A^3 - 2 I = 0$$

If $A-2^{1/3} I$ was invertibile, you could deduce that

$$A^2+ 2^{1/3}A + 2^{2/3}I = 0$$

And now we deduce... Nothing!!

Indeed, consider the matrix $A = 2^{1/3} T_{2 \pi/3}$, where $T_{\theta}$ is the matrix corresponding to the rotation of an angle $\theta$ in the plane. This satisfies $A^3= 2I$ , but $A-2^{1/3}I = 2^{1/3}( T_{2 \pi/3} - I) $ is invertible! Indeed, the only vector satisfying the system

$$ (T_{2\pi/3} - I) x = 0 $$
$$ T_{2\pi/3} x = x $$

Is the zero vector. This happens because the rotation has no other fixed points.